# insert into syntax error

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net

```
Private databaseConnector As DatabaseConnector
    Dim fulltxtSQL As String


    DatabaseConnector = New DatabaseConnector



    Try

        fulltxtSQL = "insert into [user-table] (username, password) VALUES ('" & UserName.Text & "','" & Password.Text & "')"

        DatabaseConnector.RunSqlNonQuery(fulltxtSQL)

        If DatabaseConnector.RunSqlNonQuery(fulltxtSQL) = True Then

            MsgBox("thank you for registering ", vbInformation, Title.Trim)
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")

            Exit Sub

        Else
            MsgBox(MsgBox("There has been a error in your registering", vbInformation, Title.Trim))
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.Trim, MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, Me.Title.Trim)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
End Sub
```

am trying to get the data from textbox to the database table.
 syntax error in insert into statement the connection to the database works fine but when it reaches the insert into statement i get the error

Comment: You should use parameterized queries to prevent sql injection

Comment: Your code is very insecure.  It will very easy for anyone to find out all the passwords in your table.  You should read about Sql Injection for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO [user-table] ([username],[password]) VALUES('" & UserName.Text & "','" & Password.Text & "')"
```

You query contains special character such as `user`,`table` and `password` so it will give error. So what you need to do is to put such characters in paranthesis `[]`.

Also you should use `parameterized` query.

Comment: okay the problem is fixed thanks alot for the help love this website

Comment: You should use parameterized query it will prevent sql injection.

Comment: yah i will be working on improving my website that once am done with the other pages

Answer (score 0):

try using this command

```
cmd = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [user-table] ([username],[password]) VALUES('" & UserName.Text & "','" & Password.Text & "')", con)
```

if your table name contains such special charaters then use square brackets.